# How I can connect matlab application to cloud

Tags: matlab

I want to send my **matlab appliaction output to cloud** ,output is nothing but a number.So that that my mobile application can fetch that count.So how I can connect to cloud

Comment: Search on google ?

Comment: This question is not about matlab, this question is about the API of your cloud provider.

Comment: Please provide us more information with your question. What type of output you need, what service provider you use etc.